# I want to make a system that tests for a specific player at specific coordinates with a specific item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a system that tests for a specific player at specific coordinates with a specific item?  And also how do I get one redstone output out of all the commands at once?
I tried to do /testfor [x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=R]
And /testfor  {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:slime_ball"}]}
Both work, but I can't test for 1 specific player, I can **only** check for **all** the players, I need help please.

Answer (score 2):

you can check all of that in one command like this:

```
/testfor @p[name=PlayerName,x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=R] {Inventory:[{id:minecraft:slime_ball}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

In 1.13+, you need to use `/execute if entity` in lieu of `/testfor`. There are also some additional changes you need to be aware of:

- You need to move the NBT data inside the target selector, using the `nbt` argument.
- You need to replace the `r` argument with the `distance` argument, and it's done a little differently.
- You can also implement a single command to run when the test passes.

So here is the 1.13+ way to do it:

```
/execute if entity @p[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,distance=0..5,nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:slime_ball"}]}] run ...
```

This command will only run if a player has a slime ball within five blocks of coordinates (X, Y, Z).